# Ruby 2D indexer

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing

How to implement proper 2D indexer with the following class? The following was my first shot

```
class MyArray

  #init 2D array, set all elements at 0
  def initialize(size)
    @array = []
    0.upto(size - 1) {|x|
      @array[x] = []
      0.upto(size - 1) {|y|
        @array[x][y] = 0
      }
    }
  end

  def [](*args)
    @array[args[0]][args[1]]
  end

  def []=(*args)
    @array[args[0]][args[1]] = args[2]
  end

end
```

and it works just fine for

```
test = MyArray.new(3)
test[1, 1] = 5
```

but I would like to make it working also for

```
test[1][1] = 5
```

which now gives a compilation error

> in `[]': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)

in the `[]` method.

Comment: What should `test[1]` return?

Comment: @Stefan The second line of a 2D grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there is any need for a class for that task in Ruby. create and index a 2d array is ruby is very simple :

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > a = Array.new(3){[]}  #create a array with 3 rows
 => [[], [], []]  
1.9.3p194 :002 > a[1][2]=3             #assignment
 => 3 
1.9.3p194 :003 > a[1][2]               #index 
 => 3 
1.9.3p194 :004 > a
 => [[], [nil, nil, 3], []]
```